# how to jump back before for loop and update variable until meet my requirments

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am scraping nested text from parent category and child category.
here my loop look like:

```
first for loop will scrape all parent category:
      ...seond for loop will scrape child1 category of parent category
          ...third for loop will scrape child2 category of child1 category
```

I am trying to scrape all parent and child category from this [page](https://www.daraz.com.bd/)

If my `"sub_cat_1 = y.text"` **None or empty string** then I want to increment by 1 `Level_1_Category_No{increment_by_1}` here my this variable `sub_category_one = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR , ".Level_1_Category_No1 .lzd-site-menu-sub-item > a span")`  here is my full code:

```
    driver.get("https://www.daraz.com.bd/")
    time.sleep(10)
    main_category = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR , '.lzd-site-menu-root-item span')
    with open("all_category_subcat.csv", "w",encoding="utf-8",newline="") as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(["Main Category", "Sub Category 1", "Sub Category 2"])
    
        for i in main_category:
            hover = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(i)
            hover.perform()
            main_cat = i.text
            print(main_cat)
            
            sub_category_one = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR , ".Level_1_Category_No1 .lzd-site-menu-sub-item > a span")
            for y in sub_category_one:
                hover = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(y)
                hover.perform()
                sub_cat_1 = y.text
                print("--------------",sub_cat_1,"--------------")
                if sub_cat_1 == None sub_cat_1 == "":
                       #update the value of sub_category_one and run for loop again 
                sub_category_two = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR , ".lzd-site-menu-grand-active span")           
                for z in sub_category_two:
                            sub_cat_2 = z.text
                            print(sub_cat_2)
                            writer.writerow([main_cat, sub_cat_1, sub_cat_2])
```

Comment: What do you mean? What are you trying to do? It is unclear what your question is. Are you trying to only run the sub_category_two loop if the conditions of your if statement are met?

Comment: Andrew Ryan I updated my question

Comment: can you put the second for on a separate function and just call said function after updating your variable passing it as a variable to the method?  You can't jump back into your code but you can move your code elsewhere and call it repeatedly until requirements are met.

Comment: @boyenec give below a go

Answer (score 0):

out = driver.execute_script('''
out = [];
els = document.querySelectorAll('.lzd-site-menu-root-item');
els.forEach(function(a) {
txt1 = a.querySelector('a').textContent.replaceAll('\n', '').replaceAll('  ', '').trim();
els2 = document.querySelector('.lzd-site-menu-sub.' + a.getAttribute('id')).children;

//Archived version / screenshot shows all results:

[image]
for(i=0;i<=els2.length-1;i++){ b = els2[i];
url_2 = b.querySelector('a').href;
txt2 = url_2.split('/')[3]
els3 = b.querySelectorAll('.lzd-site-menu-grand-item');
els3.forEach(function(c) {
url_3 = c.querySelector('a').href;
txt3 = url_3.split('/')[3]
out.push([txt1, txt2, url_2, txt3, url_3]);
});

```
        }
        }); 
return out''');
print(out)
```

Which gives you output like this - which is what I believe you're actually after at the end of the day?

> [["Women's Fashion", 'womens-clothing', 'https://www.daraz.com.bd/womens-clothing/?price=999-&service=OS&from=filter', 'womens-dresses', 'https://www.daraz.com.bd/womens-dresses/?from=filter&price=1200-&service=OS&from=filter/'],
>
> ["Women's Fashion", 'womens-clothing', 'https://www.daraz.com.bd/womens-clothing/?price=999-&service=OS&from=filter', 'womens-jeggings', 'https://www.daraz.com.bd/womens-jeggings/?service=OS&from=filter/'],
>
> ["Women's Fashion", 'womens-clothing', 'https://www.daraz.com.bd/womens-clothing/?price=999-&service=OS&from=filter', 'womens-kurtis', 'https://www.daraz.com.bd/womens-kurtis/?from=filter&service=OS&price=1299-'],
> ...
> ...
>
> ['Health & Beauty', 'bath-body', 'https://www.daraz.com.bd/bath-body/?service=OS&from=filter', 'body-oils', 'https://www.daraz.com.bd/body-oils/?spm=a2a0e.home.cate_2_1.1.735212f73vbvt5&service=OS&from=filter'],
> ...
> ...
>
> ['Watches, Bags, Jewellery', 'school-bags', 'https://www.daraz.com.bd/school-bags/', 'kids-backpacks', 'https://www.daraz.com.bd/kids-backpacks/'],
>
> ['Watches, Bags, Jewellery', 'school-bags', 'https://www.daraz.com.bd/school-bags/', 'kids-shoulder-bags', 'https://www.daraz.com.bd/kids-shoulder-bags/'],
>
> ['Watches, Bags, Jewellery', 'school-bags', 'https://www.daraz.com.bd/school-bags/', 'school-bags-backpack', 'https://www.daraz.com.bd/school-bags-backpack/'],
> ....
> ....
> ['Automotive & Motorbike', 'automotive', 'https://www.daraz.com.bd/automotive/?spm=a2a0e.home.cate_12.1.735212f73vbvt5', 'motorcycle-helmets', 'https://www.daraz.com.bd/motorcycle-helmets/'],
>
> ['Automotive & Motorbike', 'automotive', 'https://www.daraz.com.bd/automotive/?spm=a2a0e.home.cate_12.1.735212f73vbvt5', 'motorcycle-tools-maintenance', 'https://www.daraz.com.bd/motorcycle-tools-maintenance/']]

notes:
*(abridged version, bonus = respective urls can be discarded as required; code needs to be amended - no 'hover'/ for loops besides within the query).*